Unable to reduce glue pyspark job log size by changing log level to ERROR
Setup
We have multiple data-pipelines reading data from DynamoDB tables, processing it in Glue (pyspark job) and uploading data to Redshift. The glue version is 4.0
Issue
Our Cloudwatch bill skyrocketed (~$3K) due to PutLogEvents ingested data > 5TB size. The respective AWS account is new and only has our data warehouse project. So, we are sure that these charges came from Glue itself.
Action Taken
We started logging to verbose level 'ERROR' by applying custom log4j2 file, both based on this AWS recommendation . With this, we observed that glue-job/output metric started logging exceptions if any but glue-job/error metric still logs everything at INFO level. We think these are glue operational/ infrastructure logs and there is no direct way to change their verbose level.
Help/Pointers needed on
Anyone who has successfully applied log4j2.properties file for the glue pyspark job, do you still see INFO level logs? Is there something we are doing wrong, perhaps our log4j2 content is wrong?
Our code snippet that sets logging for both python and spark driver:
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrameCollection
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, when, expr, regexp_replace, explode, lit, udf, struct, split, trim
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType, ArrayType, MapType, TimestampType, IntegerType
import re
import json
import logging
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone


#Initializing logging
MSG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(format=MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=DATETIME_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger('Starting job')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR") #This is to set spark driver log level to ERROR
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

To set log level of spark executors, below is our log4j2 file:
# Root logger at ERROR level
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

# Console Appender
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = ConsoleAppender
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Set root logger level and appender
rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.appenderRefs = ConsoleAppender
rootLogger.appenderRef.ConsoleAppender.ref = ConsoleAppender```


TIA! Any pointers/help is appreciated.

